# Sorting the JSON Response by Last Name

Tags: javascript, json

```
{"PatientSearchResult":{"Patient":[{"AccountBalanceCalcMethod":2,"AlternatePatientID":0,"AssignmentOfBenifits":0,"CellPhoneNumber1":null,"CellPhoneNumber2":null,"Citizenship":0,"Credential":0,"DateOfBirth":null,"Deceased":0,"DeceasedDate":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/","DoesPatientHaveResidentProof":false,"DriversLicenseNumber":null,"DriversLicenseState":0,"EmailAddress1":null,"EmailAddress2":null,"Enabled":false,"Ethnicity":0,"Firstname":"2914 FirstName","FullName":"2914 FirstName 2914 LastName","Gender":2,"GuarantorID":0,"IsFinancialRisk":false,"IsPatient":false,"LastName":"2914 LastName","LocalName":null,"MaidenName":null,"MaritalStatus":0,"MiddleName1":null,"MiddleName2":null,"MothersMaidenName":null,"Nickname":null,"NoteText":null,"Notes":null,"Occupation":null,"OriginalPatientID":0,"PagerNumber":null,"PersonID":0,"PharmacyName":null,"PharmacyNoteID":0,"PhoneNumber1":null,"PhoneNumber2":null,"Prefix":0,"PrimaryLanguage":0,"PrimaryPhoneNumber":null,"PrimaryPhysID":0,"PrimaryWorkPhone":null,"Race":0,"ReleaseOfInformation":false,"Religion":0,"ResidentialAddress":null,"SSN":null,"SealedFlagID":0,"SecondaryLanguage":0,"StudentStatusID":0,"Suffix":0,"PatientID":2914},{"AccountBalanceCalcMethod":2,"AlternatePatientID":0,"AssignmentOfBenifits":0,"CellPhoneNumber1":null,"CellPhoneNumber2":null,"Citizenship":0,"Credential":0,"DateOfBirth":"\/Date(378709200000-0500)\/","Deceased":0,"DeceasedDate":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/","DoesPatientHaveResidentProof":false,"DriversLicenseNumber":null,"DriversLicenseState":0,"EmailAddress1":null,"EmailAddress2":null,"Enabled":false,"Ethnicity":0,"Firstname":"4261 FirstName","FullName":"4261 FirstName 4261 LastName","Gender":2,"GuarantorID":0,"IsFinancialRisk":false,"IsPatient":false,"LastName":"4261 LastName","LocalName":null,"MaidenName":null,"MaritalStatus":0,"MiddleName1":null,"MiddleName2":null,"MothersMaidenName":null,"Nickname":null,"NoteText":null,"Notes":null,"Occupation":null,"OriginalPatientID":0,"PagerNumber":null,"PersonID":0,"PharmacyName":null,"PharmacyNoteID":0,"PhoneNumber1":null,"PhoneNumber2":null,"Prefix":0,"PrimaryLanguage":0,"PrimaryPhoneNumber":null,"PrimaryPhysID":0,"PrimaryWorkPhone":null,"Race":0,"ReleaseOfInformation":false,"Religion":0,"ResidentialAddress":null,"SSN":null,"SealedFlagID":0,"SecondaryLanguage":0,"StudentStatusID":0,"Suffix":0,"PatientID":4261},{"AccountBalanceCalcMethod":2,"AlternatePatientID":0,"AssignmentOfBenifits":0,"CellPhoneNumber1":null,"CellPhoneNumber2":null,"Citizenship":0,"Credential":0,"DateOfBirth":"\/Date(1136264400000-0500)\/","Deceased":0,"DeceasedDate":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/","DoesPatientHaveResidentProof":false,"DriversLicenseNumber":null,"DriversLicenseState":0,"EmailAddress1":null,"EmailAddress2":null,"Enabled":false,"Ethnicity":0,"Firstname":"Bo","FullName":"Bo Ray","Gender":2,"GuarantorID":0,"IsFinancialRisk":false,"IsPatient":false,"LastName":"Ray","LocalName":null,"MaidenName":null,"MaritalStatus":0,"MiddleName1":null,"MiddleName2":null,"MothersMaidenName":null,"Nickname":null,"NoteText":null,"Notes":null,"Occupation":null,"OriginalPatientID":0,"PagerNumber":null,"PersonID":0,"PharmacyName":null,"PharmacyNoteID":0,"PhoneNumber1":null,"PhoneNumber2":null,"Prefix":0,"PrimaryLanguage":0,"PrimaryPhoneNumber":null,"PrimaryPhysID":0,"PrimaryWorkPhone":null,"Race":0,"ReleaseOfInformation":false,"Religion":0,"ResidentialAddress":null,"SSN":null,"SealedFlagID":0,"SecondaryLanguage":0,"StudentStatusID":0,"Suffix":0,"PatientID":19369},{"AccountBalanceCalcMethod":2,"AlternatePatientID":0,"AssignmentOfBenifits":0,"CellPhoneNumber1":null,"CellPhoneNumber2":null,"Citizenship":0,"Credential":0,"DateOfBirth":"\/Date(-2192126400000-0400)\/","Deceased":0,"DeceasedDate":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/","DoesPatientHaveResidentProof":false,"DriversLicenseNumber":null,"DriversLicenseState":0,"EmailAddress1":null,"EmailAddress2":null,"Enabled":false,"Ethnicity":0,"Firstname":"Mark","FullName":"Mark Noyce","Gender":2,"GuarantorID":0,"IsFinancialRisk":false,"IsPatient":false,"LastName":"Noyce","LocalName":null,"MaidenName":null,"MaritalStatus":0,"MiddleName1":null,"MiddleName2":null,"MothersMaidenName":null,"Nickname":null,"NoteText":null,"Notes":null,"Occupation":null,"OriginalPatientID":0,"PagerNumber":null,"PersonID":0,"PharmacyName":null,"PharmacyNoteID":0,"PhoneNumber1":null,"PhoneNumber2":null,"Prefix":0,"PrimaryLanguage":0,"PrimaryPhoneNumber":null,"PrimaryPhysID":0,"PrimaryWorkPhone":null,"Race":0,"ReleaseOfInformation":false,"Religion":0,"ResidentialAddress":null,"SSN":null,"SealedFlagID":0,"SecondaryLanguage":0,"StudentStatusID":0,"Suffix":0,"PatientID":19387},{"AccountBalanceCalcMethod":2,"AlternatePatientID":0,"AssignmentOfBenifits":0,"CellPhoneNumber1":null,"CellPhoneNumber2":null,"Citizenship":0,"Credential":0,"DateOfBirth":"\/Date(-5347800000000-0400)\/","Deceased":0,"DeceasedDate":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/","DoesPatientHaveResidentProof":false,"DriversLicenseNumber":null,"DriversLicenseState":0,"EmailAddress1":null,"EmailAddress2":null,"Enabled":false,"Ethnicity":0,"Firstname":"Kevin","FullName":"Kevin Noyce","Gender":2,"GuarantorID":0,"IsFinancialRisk":false,"IsPatient":false,"LastName":"Noyce","LocalName":null,"MaidenName":null,"MaritalStatus":0,"MiddleName1":null,"MiddleName2":null,"MothersMaidenName":null,"Nickname":null,"NoteText":null,"Notes":null,"Occupation":null,"OriginalPatientID":0,"PagerNumber":null,"PersonID":0,"PharmacyName":null,"PharmacyNoteID":0,"PhoneNumber1":null,"PhoneNumber2":null,"Prefix":0,"PrimaryLanguage":0,"PrimaryPhoneNumber":null,"PrimaryPhysID":0,"PrimaryWorkPhone":null,"Race":0,"ReleaseOfInformation":false,"Religion":0,"ResidentialAddress":null,"SSN":null,"SealedFlagID":0,"SecondaryLanguage":0,"StudentStatusID":0,"Suffix":0,"PatientID":19388},{"AccountBalanceCalcMethod":2,"AlternatePatientID":0,"AssignmentOfBenifits":0,"CellPhoneNumber1":null,"CellPhoneNumber2":null,"Citizenship":0,"Credential":0,"DateOfBirth":"\/Date(-381697200000-0500)\/","Deceased":0,"DeceasedDate":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/","DoesPatientHaveResidentProof":false,"DriversLicenseNumber":null,"DriversLicenseState":0,"EmailAddress1":null,"EmailAddress2":null,"Enabled":false,"Ethnicity":0,"Firstname":"Scott","FullName":"Scott Noyce","Gender":2,"GuarantorID":0,"IsFinancialRisk":false,"IsPatient":false,"LastName":"Noyce","LocalName":null,"MaidenName":null,"MaritalStatus":0,"MiddleName1":null,"MiddleName2":null,"MothersMaidenName":null,"Nickname":null,"NoteText":null,"Notes":null,"Occupation":null,"OriginalPatientID":0,"PagerNumber":null,"PersonID":0,"PharmacyName":null,"PharmacyNoteID":0,"PhoneNumber1":null,"PhoneNumber2":null,"Prefix":0,"PrimaryLanguage":0,"PrimaryPhoneNumber":null,"PrimaryPhysID":0,"PrimaryWorkPhone":null,"Race":0,"ReleaseOfInformation":false,"Religion":0,"ResidentialAddress":null,"SSN":null,"SealedFlagID":0,"SecondaryLanguage":0,"StudentStatusID":0,"Suffix":0,"PatientID":19389},{"AccountBalanceCalcMethod":2,"AlternatePatientID":0,"AssignmentOfBenifits":0,"CellPhoneNumber1":null,"CellPhoneNumber2":null,"Citizenship":0,"Credential":0,"DateOfBirth":"\/Date(-445806000000-0500)\/","Deceased":0,"DeceasedDate":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/","DoesPatientHaveResidentProof":false,"DriversLicenseNumber":null,"DriversLicenseState":0,"EmailAddress1":null,"EmailAddress2":null,"Enabled":false,"Ethnicity":0,"Firstname":"John","FullName":"John Doe","Gender":2,"GuarantorID":0,"IsFinancialRisk":false,"IsPatient":false,"LastName":"Doe","LocalName":null,"MaidenName":null,"MaritalStatus":0,"MiddleName1":null,"MiddleName2":null,"MothersMaidenName":null,"Nickname":null,"NoteText":null,"Notes":null,"Occupation":null,"OriginalPatientID":0,"PagerNumber":null,"PersonID":0,"PharmacyName":null,"PharmacyNoteID":0,"PhoneNumber1":null,"PhoneNumber2":null,"Prefix":0,"PrimaryLanguage":0,"PrimaryPhoneNumber":null,"PrimaryPhysID":0,"PrimaryWorkPhone":null,"Race":0,"ReleaseOfInformation":false,"Religion":0,"ResidentialAddress":null,"SSN":null,"SealedFlagID":0,"SecondaryLanguage":0,"StudentStatusID":0,"Suffix":0,"PatientID":19395},{"AccountBalanceCalcMethod":2,"AlternatePatientID":0,"AssignmentOfBenifits":0,"CellPhoneNumber1":null,"CellPhoneNumber2":null,"Citizenship":0,"Credential":0,"DateOfBirth":"\/Date(-880830000000-0500)\/","Deceased":0,"DeceasedDate":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/","DoesPatientHaveResidentProof":false,"DriversLicenseNumber":null,"DriversLicenseState":0,"EmailAddress1":null,"EmailAddress2":null,"Enabled":false,"Ethnicity":0,"Firstname":"Dagwood","FullName":"Dagwood Bumstead","Gender":2,"GuarantorID":0,"IsFinancialRisk":false,"IsPatient":false,"LastName":"Bumstead","LocalName":null,"MaidenName":null,"MaritalStatus":0,"MiddleName1":null,"MiddleName2":null,"MothersMaidenName":null,"Nickname":null,"NoteText":null,"Notes":null,"Occupation":null,"OriginalPatientID":0,"PagerNumber":null,"PersonID":0,"PharmacyName":null,"PharmacyNoteID":0,"PhoneNumber1":null,"PhoneNumber2":null,"Prefix":0,"PrimaryLanguage":0,"PrimaryPhoneNumber":null,"PrimaryPhysID":0,"PrimaryWorkPhone":null,"Race":0,"ReleaseOfInformation":false,"Religion":0,"ResidentialAddress":null,"SSN":null,"SealedFlagID":0,"SecondaryLanguage":0,"StudentStatusID":0,"Suffix":0,"PatientID":19414},{"AccountBalanceCalcMethod":2,"AlternatePatientID":0,"AssignmentOfBenifits":0,"CellPhoneNumber1":null,"CellPhoneNumber2":null,"Citizenship":0,"Credential":0,"DateOfBirth":null,"Deceased":0,"DeceasedDate":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/","DoesPatientHaveResidentProof":false,"DriversLicenseNumber":null,"DriversLicenseState":0,"EmailAddress1":null,"EmailAddress2":null,"Enabled":false,"Ethnicity":0,"Firstname":"Clyde","FullName":"Clyde Barrow","Gender":2,"GuarantorID":0,"IsFinancialRisk":false,"IsPatient":false,"LastName":"Barrow","LocalName":null,"MaidenName":null,"MaritalStatus":0,"MiddleName1":null,"MiddleName2":null,"MothersMaidenName":null,"Nickname":null,"NoteText":null,"Notes":null,"Occupation":null,"OriginalPatientID":0,"PagerNumber":null,"PersonID":0,"PharmacyName":null,"PharmacyNoteID":0,"PhoneNumber1":null,"PhoneNumber2":null,"Prefix":0,"PrimaryLanguage":0,"PrimaryPhoneNumber":null,"PrimaryPhysID":0,"PrimaryWorkPhone":null,"Race":0,"ReleaseOfInformation":false,"Religion":0,"ResidentialAddress":null,"SSN":null,"SealedFlagID":0,"SecondaryLanguage":0,"StudentStatusID":0,"Suffix":0,"PatientID":19415},{"AccountBalanceCalcMethod":2,"AlternatePatientID":0,"AssignmentOfBenifits":0,"CellPhoneNumber1":null,"CellPhoneNumber2":null,"Citizenship":0,"Credential":0,"DateOfBirth":"\/Date(-249678000000-0500)\/","Deceased":0,"DeceasedDate":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/","DoesPatientHaveResidentProof":false,"DriversLicenseNumber":null,"DriversLicenseState":0,"EmailAddress1":null,"EmailAddress2":null,"Enabled":false,"Ethnicity":0,"Firstname":"Fred","FullName":"Fred Flintstone","Gender":2,"GuarantorID":0,"IsFinancialRisk":false,"IsPatient":false,"LastName":"Flintstone","LocalName":null,"MaidenName":null,"MaritalStatus":0,"MiddleName1":null,"MiddleName2":null,"MothersMaidenName":null,"Nickname":null,"NoteText":null,"Notes":null,"Occupation":null,"OriginalPatientID":0,"PagerNumber":null,"PersonID":0,"PharmacyName":null,"PharmacyNoteID":0,"PhoneNumber1":null,"PhoneNumber2":null,"Prefix":0,"PrimaryLanguage":0,"PrimaryPhoneNumber":null,"PrimaryPhysID":0,"PrimaryWorkPhone":null,"Race":0,"ReleaseOfInformation":false,"Religion":0,"ResidentialAddress":null,"SSN":null,"SealedFlagID":0,"SecondaryLanguage":0,"StudentStatusID":0,"Suffix":0,"PatientID":19420}]}}
```

This is my JSON response, how would i sort it. What i tried.

```
var data = eval(PatientSearchResponse);
var results = data['results'];

PatientSearchResponse.SortByName(results);

function SortByName(x,y) {      
  return ((x.LastName == y.LastName) ? 0 : ((x.LastName > y.LastName) ? 1 : -1 ));    
}
```

It did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few problems here; `results` does not exist in the JSON response you gave, and `SortByName` is a function available to the current scope, but is not a member of `PatientSearchResponse`.

Presumably, you want something like this:

```
var data = eval(PatientSearchResponse); // use JSON.parse if available
var results = data['PatientSearchResult'];

// Call the `sort` method, passing SortByName as the first argument
results.Patient.sort(SortByName);

function SortByName(x,y) {      
  return ((x.LastName == y.LastName) ? 0 : ((x.LastName > y.LastName) ? 1 : -1 ));    
}
```

Comment: Why not use eval... use JSON.parse and what does PatientSearchResult and Patient mean in my JSON response

Comment: @John: `PatientSearchResult` and `Patient` are just field names - the former contains the latter in your JSON sample.  `eval` is considered unsafe for parsing JSON unless you perform several safety checks beforehand.  `JSON.parse` is a native parser built into modern browsers but may not be available to older browsers.

Comment: Its working, now should i alert(PatientSearchResult) or alert(results)

Comment: @John: neither - `PatientSearchResult` contains the original, unsorted string and `results` is an object.  Use your browser's developer console if you're debugging, `console.dir(results)`.

Comment: as alert(results) gives me Java.lang expection

Answer (score 0):

I dont know which server side scripting you are using, if its PHP then

Try [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) , this will unserialize the json object into an array (only if ur json data format is correct).

Then you can sort the array using array sorting functions.